# Excel file generation on server without Excel installed

Tags: asp.net, excel, office-interop

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and generating Excel files using the `SaveAs` method.  This all works correctly on  computer with Excel installed.  However, my server does not have Excel installed.

How can I generate my files?

Comment: Don't ever use Office Interop from an ASP.NET application. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 4):

<del>If you generate a file using Interop you need to install Excel on the server.</del>

Microsoft doesn't support installing Excel (or Word) on the server. Instead you should download the Office Open XML SDK from Microsoft and use that library to generate Excel 2007 documents. This library does not require Excel to be installed on the server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee441239.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about Excel prior to MS Office 2010, there is no set of "client libraries" that can be used to create Office documents.
"Interop" assemblies are just .net wrappers around Microsoft's unmanaged code, that make the Excel API available to .net clients.
You will have to install MSOffice on the server.

EDIT: A similar question here: [Excel dll for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564443/excel-dll-for-microsoft-office-interop-excel)

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford a third party library, [Spreadsheetgear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is a good investement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) library to read and write Excel (and others) files.

> "The FileHelpers are a free and easy to use .NET library to import/export data from fixed length or delimited records in files, strings or streams."

It works well for me, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with the new Open Office Xml format (xlsx) I would highly recommend taking a look at  the free .Net library [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). It is easy to use and has a ton of features.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need data in the files and no graphs etc, I would just go with XML or CSV format. Both are open formats and don't require interop binaries.